# I want to improve the quality of MeshPhongMaterial

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

First of all, please understand that I am not good at English.

I'm using react three fiber so hard. I uploaded the obj file using OBJLoader.

In this way, image A was rendered. But the quality is very, very bad...

I want to increase the quality like image B.

I don't know if I matched the map of the material incorrectly
What should I do??

Thanks for sharing your wisdom

Image A

[image]

Image B
[image]

```
import React, {useMemo, useRef, useEffect, useState, Suspense} from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {Canvas, useFrame, useGraph, useLoader, useThree, createPortal, ObjectMap} from "@react-three/fiber";
import {OrbitControls, OrthographicCamera, useCamera, Html, useProgress, Stats, Center} from "@react-three/drei";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {OBJLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'
import {CameraControls, CameraControlsType} from "./cameraControls";
import LightController from "./lightController";
// @ts-ignore
import objectImage from 'assets/images/NT_NO061/NT_NO061.obj';
import aoMapImage from 'assets/images/NT_NO061/Textures/T_NT_NO061_AO.png';
import mapImage from 'assets/images/NT_NO061/Textures/T_NT_NO061_D.png';
import normalMapImage from 'assets/images/NT_NO061/Textures/T_NT_NO061_N.png';
import roughnessMapImage from 'assets/images/NT_NO061/Textures/T_NT_NO061_R.png';

type geometryType = {
    attach: string,
    vertices: any,
    onUpdate: any
}

type flag = {
    video: boolean,
    minimap: boolean
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    canvas {
        height: 594px
    }
`

const ReactThreeFiber = () => {
    const cameraControls = useRef<CameraControlsType | null>(null) as any;
    const [aoMap, map, normalMap, roughnessMap] = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, [
        aoMapImage,
        mapImage,
        normalMapImage,
        roughnessMapImage
    ])

    const [progressValue, setProgressValue] = useState<number>(0);
    const scene = useLoader(OBJLoader, objectImage, loader => {
        loader.manager.onProgress = (url, loaded, total) => {
            console.log('url, loaded, total', url, loaded, total)
        }
    }) as any;
    
    const {nodes} = useGraph(scene) as ObjectMap;
    const {geometry} = useMemo(() => nodes[Object.keys(nodes)[0]] as any, []);

    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

*** Question!! What should I add here to improve the quality?? ***
    material.map = map;
    material.normalMap = normalMap;
    material.shininess = 70;

    let startPoint = 3
    const lookAtPos = new THREE.Vector3()

    return (
      <Wrapper>
          <Canvas
            camera={{position: [3, 3, 3]}}
            onCreated={({scene}) => scene.background = new THREE.Color('#000')}
            frameloop={'demand'}
          >
              <CameraControls
                ref={cameraControls}
                minDistance={2}
                maxDistance={7}
              />
              <LightController/>
              <OrbitControls/>
              <Center>
                  <mesh
                    position={[0, -2, 0]}
                    geometry={geometry}
                    material={material}
                  />
              </Center>
              <Stats/>
          </Canvas>
      </Wrapper>
    );
}

export default React.memo(ReactThreeFiber);
```

Comment: I think Phong won't achieve the look you're trying to get. You should consider using [MeshPhysicalMaterial](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=physical#webgl_materials_physical_clearcoat) with clearcoat enabled to get that reflective sheen.

Comment: i got it!! Thank you very much!! Sorry but I have one more question...!
No matter how much I change to MeshPhongMaterial, the stutter doesn't go away...
Is there any other way other than computer performance...? 
I need some advice...